# Operations within rows in R

Tags: r, syntax, row

Consider the following dataset, where:

- Variables 1-7 (`var1-7`) are linear measurements taken from five lizards (`indvA-E`);
- Variable 8 (`var8`) is the number of variables, for each lizard, that contain values that are not equal to NA;
- Variable 9 (`var9`) is the sum of variables 1-7;

```
data <- data.frame(var1 = c(0.13,0.08,0.05,0.11,0.09),
                   var2 = c(0.17,0.09,0.07,0.15,0.13),
                   var3 = c(0.19,0.11,0.19,0.17,0.14),
                   var4 = c(NA,0.11,0.31,0.38,0.17),
                   var5 = c(NA,NA,0.39,0.41,0.19),
                   var6 = c(NA,NA,0.40,0.75,NA),
                   var7 = c(NA,NA,0.45,0.79,NA))
    
row.names(data) <- c("indv.A","indv.B","indv.C","indv.D","indv.E")
    
data[,"var8"] <- rowSums(!is.na(data))
    
data[,"var9"] <- rowSums(data[,1:7], na.rm = TRUE)
    
data
    
#        var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9
# indv.A 0.13 0.17 0.19   NA   NA   NA   NA    3 0.49
# indv.B 0.08 0.09 0.11 0.11   NA   NA   NA    4 0.39
# indv.C 0.05 0.07 0.19 0.31 0.39 0.40 0.45    7 1.86
# indv.D 0.11 0.15 0.17 0.38 0.41 0.75 0.79    7 2.76
# indv.E 0.09 0.13 0.14 0.17 0.19   NA   NA    5 0.72
```

I'd like to create a new variable, named `var10`, that can be described as either "*var8 divided by (var7 minus the last non-NA value of variables 1-7)*" or "*var8 divided by all but the last non-NA value of variables 1-7*".

For the above dataset, this new variable will contain:

```
#         var1-9  var10
# indv.A  [...]   10.00
# indv.B  [...]   14.29
# indv.C  [...]   4.96
# indv.D  [...]   3.55
# indv.E  [...]   9.43
```

I just don't know how to write in R the formula to obtain this variable. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** If we need the last non-NA value from var1 to var7, we can do

```
v1 <- data[cbind(seq_len(nrow(data)), max.col(!is.na(data[1:7]), "last"))]
data$var10 <- data$var8/v1
```

**2)** For the second case to skip the last non-NA

```
data$var10 <- data$var8/
   apply(data[1:7], 1, \(x) sum(head(x[!is.na(x)], -1)))
> data$var10
[1] 10.000000 14.285714  4.964539  3.553299  9.433962
```

Comment: Many thanks! This worked perfectly. Just a simplification of the code: `x <- data[cbind(seq_len(nrow(data)), data$var8)]` and then `data$var10 <- data$var8 / (data$var9 - x)`